# AASTEX abstract not showing in TeXStudio or ShareLaTeX

Tags: texstudio, sharelatex, aastex

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{aastex6}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is a test abstract to ensure LaTeX is functioning.
\end{abstract}

testing
\end{document}
```

I compile this code in TeXstudio and get a blank page with a page number at the top and only the word 'testing' in the upper left hand corner. No abstract is visible anywhere on the page. In addition, if I add titles or authors, those too do not display correctly.

The exactly same thing happens in ShareLaTeX when I upload the aastex.cls file.

I would like to know how I can make my abstract, title, authors, and other environments display correctly. I am completely new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inorder to make the title, author, affiliation, abstract etc (title part) appear in the PDF, you should give `\maketitle` command after abstract. But in the class file `\maketitle` is automatically called when you give first `\section{}` command. The following examples will now work:

```
\documentclass{aastex6}
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is a test abstract to ensure LaTeX is functioning.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
testing
\end{document}
```

You could download [this](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex/aastexv6.0.zip) zip file and use the sample.tex file included in the archive as a template for your submission.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem, which had the same symptom.
 I fix it by moving the \title{} and \author{} fields *before* \begin{document}
 This worked in Sharelatex:

\documentclass[12pt,preprint]{aastex}

\shortauthors{xx, et al.}
\shorttitle{A title}

\title{A long title.}

\author{
   Joe \textsc{Bloggs}\altaffilmark{1}
}
 \affil{$^1$ What ever}
 \email{xx.yy@zz.org}
%%% end:list of authors

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} 
Abstract
\end{abstract}
%\maketitle
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intr}

Comment: This doesn't provide anything new that isn't already provided in the answer, since `\author`, `\title`, `\affil` and `\email` also forms part of the title set by `\maketitle`.